# Delete highly upvoted opinion based questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, opinion-based

I was running through the Reopen queue and this question popped up

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097305/what-should-be-the-preferable-redis-client-in-golang

There's some sharp comments about it being closed for being opinion based. But it has 8 up votes. I don't want to rehash the opinion-based debate, I just want to know if it's appropriate to vote for deletion of question like this when it has so many up votes and no answers due to closure.

Comment: Deletion was absolutely right, in my view - that question is **not** on-topic here, irrespective of whether the (nine?!) upvoters found it interesting, and it's hard to imagine an edit that would make it acceptable. It wouldn't even be on-topic at SoftwareRecs, as it lacks a specific purpose and evaluation criteria.

Comment: 8 upvotes after more than two years is certainly not highly upvoted. Aside from that, it's an unanswered purely opinion-based question, which does not belong here.

Comment: Agreed with @jonsharpe and Deduplicator; No answers; opinion based; two years old; only 8 upvotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be voting to delete content that is not appropriate for the site, doesn't have useful content, and isn't something that stands much of a chance of being improved such that it will become appropriate for the site.

That question isn't appropriate for the site.

It has no useful content on it, it has no answers, and the only comments are just saying that it doesn't belong here, so there's nothing of value that would be lost if it were to be deleted.  Votes are one tool you can use to help *estimate* how useful some particular piece of content might be.  If there's an answer with 0 votes, or mostly downvotes, it's a strong indication that it wasn't helpful.  If it has hundreds of upvotes, it's a sign that it *might* be valuable content.  Not only is 8 upvotes over the course of 2 years and ~3.8k views, but there isn't anything that even attempts to be an answer; I fail to see how the question alone would be useful to anyone.

As for it being improved, I see no way for a question like this to be editable into something that's appropriate for the site.  If such a heroic edit were even possible, given that it's been two years it's pretty clearly not going to happen.

So yes, deletion is absolutely correct here.